# how to construct dynamic urls for backbone routing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, url-routing

I have complex routing here. constructing urls for subviews to navigate for different parent views.

```
domain.com/categories/1/details  
domain.com/categories/1/price  
domain.com/categories/1/owner

domain.com/categories/2/details  
domain.com/categories/2/price  
domain.com/categories/2/owner
```

I need to construct urls for details, price and owner views.

```
<a href="#/categories/id/price">Price</a>
<a href="#/categories/id/details">details</a>
<a href="#/categories/id/owner">owner</a>
```

Need to replace id dynamically!

How can I construct them?

Comment: Have you tried reading the [Backbone.Router](http://backbonejs.org/#Router) documentation?

Comment: yah. but I need to navigate for common views "categories/:id/:section" I can route it, but the problem is href="categories/?/section".

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var myRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
          routes : {}
    });
    myRouter.on('route:categories/:id/details' function() {

    });

    myRouter.on('route:categories/:id/price' function() {

    });

    myRouter.on('route:categories/:id/owner' function() {

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Within your view's template, you'd have:

```
<script type="text/template" id="my-template">
    <a href="#/categories/<%= id %>/price">Price</a>
    <a href="#/categories/<%= id %>/details">details</a>
    <a href="#/categories/<%= id %>/owner">owner</a>
</script>
```

Then within your view's render method, you just need to pass in the id variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var userId = 42;

    var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function(){
            this.render();
        },
        render: function(){
            // Compile the template using underscore
            var template = _.template( $("#my-template").html(), {id: userId});

            // Load the compiled HTML into the Backbone "el"
            this.$el.html( template );
        }
    });
</script>
```

Here is a little more on the subject that might help: http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-view/

Comment: I don't want to re-initialize the total view.

Comment: So you don't have these values when the view first initializes? If that is the case, you could just add a function to your view that dips intto the DOM, grabs the A elements, and then modifies the SRC (using jQuery).